# How to create a solid gauge chart with Highcharts in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

[image]I want to create a solid guage chart in highcharts in angular 6.I tried with other charts its working fine but guage chart is not working.I have already imported the plugin but its not able to find the type of chart.Here is the code below also I have created a demo in this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yw3xwa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts .

### app.component.html

```
<div #referenceKeyName (click)="onClickMe(referenceKeyName)" id="chart2"></div>
```

### app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { HighchartsChartModule } from "highcharts-angular";
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,HighchartsChartModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### app.component.ts

```
declare var require: any;
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
const HighchartsMore = require("highcharts/highcharts-more.src");
HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
const HC_solid_gauge = require("highcharts/modules/solid-gauge.src");
HC_solid_gauge(Highcharts);
import * as Exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  clickMessage = '';
  name = 'Angular';
  onClickMe(referenceKeyName) {
  alert(referenceKeyName.id);
}
  ngOnInit(){
  this.chartFunc('chart2');
  }
  chartFunc(chartId){
  Highcharts.chart(chartId,{
   chart: {
         'type': 'solidGauge'
      },
      title: {
         text: "Monthly Average Temperature"
      },
     'pane': {
          'center': ['50%', '50%'],
          'size': '300px',
          'startAngle': 0,
          'endAngle': 360,
          'background': {
            'backgroundColor': '#EEE',
            'innerRadius': '90%',
            'outerRadius': '100%',
            'borderWidth': 0
          }
        },
        'yAxis': {
          'min': 0,
          'max': 100,
          'labels': {
            'enabled': false
          },

          'lineWidth': 0,
          'minorTickInterval': null,
          'tickPixelInterval': 400,
          'tickWidth': 0
        },
        'plotOptions': {
            'solidgauge': {
                'innerRadius': '90%'
            }
        },
      'series': [{
            'name': 'Speed',
            'data': [50],
            'dataLabels': {
                'enabled': false
            }
        }]
   });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a simple typo. The solid gauge series is called `solidgauge` instead of `solidGauge`.

```
chart: {
  'type': 'solidgauge'
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elp56k?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: When I download and run in my system its showing above attached error.When I edit code and recompile,its compiled successfully but I am getting error.Can you please help me on it

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like codesandbox?